# Can multiple Linux machines concurrently use a Windows shared folder?

Tags: windows, mount

Is it a good idea to mount a Windows-based folder share on multiple Linux (Ubuntu) machines?

Would there be a performance drop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to mount a Windows share on multiple linux(ubuntu) machines

If it is what you need: yes. We use Ubuntu machine's here (about 100) and also have a single Windows share. Works without problems. By the way: yhe reason for shares IS to share them with others; hence the name.

> Would there be a performance drop?

Not from the amount of users. Other things will be more related to performance, like network capacity.